# Riak Search JSON list

Tags: riak, riak-search

I wonder how you can search in Riak Search for list items.

e.g.:

```
{
    "name": "Zombies Eat Brains",
    "tags": ["zombies", "funny", "lol"]
}
```

search-cmd search objects ???

Comment: Basho has a riak-users mailing list (http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com) for usage related questions and issues. It might be worthwhile posting your question there as well as it is quite active.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can search any kind of field in JSON.

E.g. in bucket 'products' I have value

```
keywords: [
"New York",
"billboard",
"outdoors"
]
```

I find the result with the search:

```
search-cmd search products "keywords:billboard"
```

Read more at

- http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.3.1/cookbooks/Riak-Search---Indexing-and-Querying-Riak-KV-Data/#JSON-Encoded-Data
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.riak.user/5443